# Test angular app which does an ajax request on startup

Tags: testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I need test components of my angular app. The Problem is every time I want to test something the karma testrunner shows me that error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /foo
No more request expected
```

After some research it was clear that the test framework blocks all requests and I need to declare every request accepted  in my test via:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET("/foo").respond("bar");
}));
```

so I can do expectations on requests.

The Problem is that it seems like I cannot initialize my $httpBackend and load my module/app after that like shown here:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET("/foo").respond("bar");
}));
beforeEach(module('myApplication'));
```

It fails with

```
Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!
```

But to load my module/app first and configure the $httpBackend after this it is too late:

```
beforeEach(module('myApplication'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET("/foo").respond("bar");
}));
```

fails with

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /foo
No more request expected
```

it fails because I need to make an ajax request inside of my application configuration `myapp.config(function(...) {.. doSomeAjax  ..}`

Any Idea how to solve the Problem?

Comment: It's a long time since you posted this question, but wanted to ask if you found a solution to this? I am currently facing the same issue.

Comment: @Nitesh I created a second module named `myApplicationTests` with the same dependencies, but replaced the `myapp.config` call with something static. I refactored all other `.config`, `.run`, `.value` and `.constant` calls into another module, so I can import them as a dependency within `myApplication` and `myApplicationTests` in order to keep things dry. I still think there must be something more simple.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first problem: You can load the modules you need like this:

```
var $httpBackend; // reference for your it() functions
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApplication');

    inject(function ($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    });
});
```

Now, about the unexpected request problem, from the [angularjs httpBackend documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend):

> The $httpBackend used in production, always responds to requests with responses asynchronously. If we preserved this behavior in unit testing, we'd have to create async unit tests, which are hard to write, follow and maintain. At the same time the testing mock, can't respond synchronously because that would change the execution of the code under test. For this reason the mock $httpBackend has a flush() method, which allows the test to explicitly flush pending requests and thus preserving the async api of the backend, while allowing the test to execute synchronously.

I'm using it a bit different than you, so my solution below is just a guess. Firstly I think you need to have a mock response. You define it with `when()...respond()`. Then, you should flush your requests:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET("/foo").respond("bar");
$httpBackend.flush();
```

I used this to test a service that made an http request in the factory. In the beforeEach clause, I first defined the mock response, then instantiated the service (`myservice = $injector('nameofservice')` and then I flushed the requests that had been triggered in the factory.

Comment: I knew about that and I like this feature.If I take your first code as an example and myApplication would be the application I am currently developing, it would make a request in the line 3 (`module('myApplication');`) and that will be executed before I make a $httpBackend in lines 5-7. I would not even reach this lines because I get an Exception in line 3. As I said, I cannot configure the $httpBackend before loading my module/app.